# Homotopy type of the self-homotopy equivalences of a bouquet of spheres

Tags: rational-homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology, loop-spaces, homotopy-theory

Before I state the questions I have in mind, let me give some background. If one considers $S^2$ then it is known due to Kneser that $\textrm{Homeo}^{+}(S^2)$ has the homotopy type of $SO(3)$. By Smale's work we also know that $\textrm{Diff}^{+}(S^2)$ is homotopic to $SO(3)$. However, when we work in the homotopy category this changes. Later Hansen considered $\textrm{Aut}_0(S^2)$, the connected component of identity in the space of all self homotopy equivalences. He showed that its homotopy type is that of $SO(3)\times \mathbf{\Omega}$, where $\mathbf{\Omega}$ is the universal cover of the connected component of the constant loop in the double loop space $\Omega^2 S^2$.

Although this is a very nice and interesting fact, it's turns out to be hard to generalize his method of proof for higher spheres. For one, the homotopy type of $\textrm{Diff}(S^n)$ is not really known for $n\geq 7$ if I'm not mistaken. For another, Hansen crucially uses the fact that $S^2$ is the base of the usual fibration $SO(2)\to SO(3)\to S^2$ and the fact $SO(2)=S^1$ has no higher homotopy. This indubitably fails for higher spheres!

**Question 1** What is known about the homotopy type of $\textrm{Aut}_0(S^n)$ for $n\geq 3$?

I should say that the rational homotopy type is fairly easily calculable via Sullivan's minimal models. So, I'm looking for a bit more here.

**Question 2** What is the homotopy type of the identity component of self homotopy equivalences of $\vee_k S^2$, a bouquet of $2$-spheres?

Of course, one can ask this question for higher spheres but bearing in mind question 1, I decided I would be happy with an answer for $S^2$. If it helps, the homotopy groups of $\vee_k S^2$ can be calculated by Hilton-Milnor theorem. This fits in a long exact sequence of groups associated to 
$\textrm{Aut}_0^\ast(\vee_k S^2)\to \textrm{Aut}_0(\vee_k S^2)\to \vee_k S^2$
where the last map is evaluation of an automorphism at the common point of the bouquet and $\textrm{Aut}^\ast_0(\vee_k S^2)$ consists of based maps. But this doesn't seem to lead anywhere!

Comment: Do you have any idea what would happen in the case of completing with respect to a prime? You seem to understand the rational information. Maybe you can put it all together to reasemble the homotopy type from the prime pieces and the rational piece. 

Comment: @Spice the Bird - You may be onto something here! Unfortunately, I have no idea of what the theory at a prime p is although I've heard people using these words. Do you have any readable reference (of the general theory and then reassembling rational and prime pieces) in mind? I can perhaps try to learn something new at least!

Comment: You might take a look at the paper of Dror-Dwyer-Kan: http://www.nd.edu/~wgd/Html/Arithmetic.Square.html

Or Sullivan's older papers (either the Annals paper referenced by the paper above or his "MIT notes" on geometric topology, which were finally published a few years ago: http://books.google.com/books/about/Geometric_topology.html?id=yiTIe-MCPoUC).

Comment: I learned of the idea from Sullivan's MIT notes.

Comment: I'm sure you realize this but  Question 2 is also amenable to  rational homotopy theory  treatment using Haefliger construction of models for $Map_f(X,Y)$. Also, given a minimal model $(M,d)$ for $X$ the differential graded lie algebra of derivations of $M$ (with the differential given by $[-,d]$)  is the Quillen Lie model for $BAut_0(X)$. Note however, that even for a wedge of two spheres (of any dimension) you'll get a rationally hyperbolic space and rational homotopy and homology of $Aut_0(X)$ will grow exponentially. So there won't be any nice answers here as there were for $Aut(S^n)$.

Comment: The group $Aut_0 (S^n)$ is usually denoted by $G_{n+1}$. The connecting homomorphism (of the fibration you defined above  in case $k=1$) $$\pi_i S^n\to \pi_{i+n-1} S^n = \pi_{i-1}\Omega^nS^n$$ is the Whitehead bracked with the identity $[id,-]$.

Comment: Similarly, the connecting homomorphism for the fibration $$\prod_{i=1}^k \Omega^k _{*\vee\ldots\vee id_i\vee\ldots \vee *}\vee_k S^n\to Aut_0(\vee_k S^n) \to \vee_k S^n$$ is given by $x\mapsto \oplus [id_i,x]$.

Answer (score 9):

Regarding question 1 the following is  well known.

For a reasonably nice space  $X$ (say, a finite connected CW-complex) let $Aut_0(X)$ be the monoid of self-equivalences of $X$ homotopic to the identity and let $Aut_0^\bullet(X)$ be the submonoid fixing a basepoint. Then there is a natural fibration given by the evaluation map $Aut_0^\bullet(X)\to Aut_0(X)\to X$. This gives rise to the fibration $X\to BAut_0^\bullet(X)\to BAut_0(X)$ which is the universal fibration with fiber $X$.

For $X=S^n$ it's easy to see that $Aut_0^\bullet(S^n)\cong Map_0^\bullet(S^n, S^n)\cong Map_0^\bullet(S^{n-1}, \Omega S^n)\cong \ldots Map_0^\bullet (S^0, \Omega^n(S^n))=\Omega^n(S^n)$. In particular, $\pi_k(Aut_0^\bullet(S^n))\cong \pi_{n+k}(S^n)$. Combining this with the fibration $Aut_0^\bullet(S^n)\to Aut_0(S^n)\to S^n$ this in principle gives you homotopy groups of $Aut_0(S^n)$. In practice though I don't think this is very useful away from rational  coefficients or for small values of $k$ where you have stability.

I'm not familiar with the general theory for spaces other than spheres. As I mentioned in my comment, rationally the situation is in principle  well understood. But even for rational coefficients the homotopy structure of $Aut_0(X)$ is complicated when $X$ is a wedge of spheres.  As I mentioned, rational homotopy groups of $Aut_0(X)$ grow exponentially. See ["The monoid of self-homotopy equivalences of some homogeneous spaces" by  Félix and Thomas](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=IID&s1=189500&vfpref=html&r=31&mx-pid=1297839) for a careful proof of that.
One general fact that I know is a [result of Dror, Dwyer and  Kan](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=IID&s1=59915&vfpref=html&r=29&mx-pid=656214)  that when $X$ is a nilpotent finite $CW$-complex then   $BAut_0(X)$ has finite type, i.e. it has the homotopy type of a CW complex with a finite number of cells in each dimension.